# Java How to add JButton to Background object?

Tags: java, object, background, jbutton

I was trying to add a JButton on Background object. This is my code:

```
     Background bg;
     JButton jb = new JButton("Oh");

     public void init(){
                    bg=new Background("/images/bg3.jpg",0);
                    bg.setVector(-0.1, 0);
                    jb.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/images/logo/build.png"));
                    jb.setSize(100, 100);
                    bg.add(jb);                    

    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g){
            bg.draw(g);
            bg.setVisible(true);

    }
```

How can I do it?

Comment: A `JButton` is a Swing component. `Background` is a JavaFX component. I don't see a sense behind this. http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm